# Unable to SSH into OpenSUSE Virtualbox Machine from my Ubuntu Focal Fossa host

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox

I am currently running Ubuntu Focal Fossa and trying to **ssh** into an OpenSuSe machine version being **openSUSE Leap 15.2**. I can **ssh** into every other machine using the **Bridge Network** configuration but for the said machine I get a

```
ssh: connect to host 10.64.40.206 port 22: No route to host
```

error. I can even ping the machine but can't just **ssh** into it. Perhaps there's a configuration setting expected on the Host to be able to **ssh** into OpenSuSe.

Comment: Is there any reason to suspect this isn't an opensuse problem?

Comment: @organicmarble I kinda suspect that as I can hit the host from opensuse. Still looking into it!